# Obtener el texto de un php

Tags: php, javascript

tengo un codigo **php** donde imprimo un ´echo´ al final de todo mi proceso es decir:

```
<?php
 /*
 aqui va todo el proceso...
 */
  echo "Proceso teminado";
 ?>
```

quiero saber si se puede cerrar la ventana del navegador una vez que aparezca ese texto. Sé de ante mano que hay un codigo en **JS** que hace se proceso de cerrar `window.close();` el tema es que lo quiero ejecutar de manera automatica, en cuanto salga el texto se cierre la venta, ¿hay forma de lograrlo?.
Saludos.

Comment: puedes probar con exit(); después de mostrar el mensaje

Comment: ¿Estás usando AJAX o no? En caso de que sea así, para hacer la petición ¿estás usando solamente JS, jQuery o alguna otra librería?

Comment: no, nada de AJAX, sólo PHP y esta parte del cerrado automatico en JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes asignar el mensaje a un elemento y despues con JS buscar ese elemento y evaluar su valor:

```
window.onload = () => {
  setInterval(()=>{
    let elem = document.getElementById('status');
    if(elem.innerText === "Proceso terminado") {
      window.location.assign("https://www.google.com.mx");
    }
  },1000);
}
```

El código se ejecuta cada segundo con la función:

```
setInterval()
```

Esta opción te permite redireccionar al usuario a otra página.

Comment: me queda la duda lo que pones el usuario ya lo sabe, aqui lo que el pregunta es como hacerlo funcionar con un bloque de código en php si lees la pregunta

Comment: Gracias, lo acabo de corregir

Comment: hola que tal este código es bastante útil pero por cuestiones de cliente, (que no termino de entender) se requiere que se cierre, por lo que observo, ¿tendría que agregar una etiqueta ´html´ para poder utilizar el ´document.getElementById('status');´ ?

Comment: Sí, disculpa el elemento "status" podría ser en donde despliegues tu mensaje poniéndolo de esta manera echo('<p id="status">Proceso terminado</p>')

Comment: Gracias, entonces un cerrado automático no se puede ejecutar?

Comment: Tendrías que ver la manera de ejecutar tu código php dentro de la nueva ventana que crees con el método window.open(), por ejemplo si tienes tus procesos en un script con dirección en http://tuempresa.com/proceso.php, podrías re direccionarlo así window.open(' http://tuempresa.com/proceso.php'), y aquí sí podrías cerrarla

Comment: El detalle que tengo es que la ventana se abre automáticamente cuando ejecuto el desarrollo, al termino aparece el mensaje "Proceso terminado", todo el desarrollo esta dentro de un **php**  tal y como lo explique al principio, de todas maneras gracias por tu código, seguiré investigando.